# How to insert DEFAULT when the variable in BindParam is null

Tags: php, pdo, insert, default-value

I'm using PDO prepared statement.
I want to BIND a variable BUT if the variable is NULL it have to INSERT in MYSQL the DEFAULT VALUE of the field.

I'm trying with
`IFNULL(:User_Login__Is_Active, DEFAULT),`
And I tried also:
`COALESCE(:User_Login__Is_Active, DEFAULT),`
Same error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

How can you do that?

Look at this example:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user_login
                                    ( User_Login__ID,
                                      User_Login__Is_Active,
                                      User_Login__Created_Date )
                               VALUES ( 
                                      :User_Login__ID,
                                      IFNULL(:User_Login__Is_Active, DEFAULT),
                                      :User_Login__Created_Date )');


$stmt->bindParam(':User_Login__ID', $this->User_Login__ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':User_Login__Is_Active', $this->User_Login__Is_Active, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$stmt->bindParam(':User_Login__Created_Date', $this->User_Login__Created_Date, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);


$this->User_Login__Is_Active = null;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keyword `DEFAULT` can't be used inside an expression, it can only replace the entire expression.

However, the function [`DEFAULT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default) can be used anywhere.

So replace `DEFAULT` in your example with `DEFAULT(User_Login__Is_Active)`.