# How to handle nulls in this PHP/mysql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, null

I sometimes have arrays with null or empty values.  In MySql they are set up to be non-nullable, but they have default values assigned.  Why then, does MySql give me an error, e.g. `Column user_type can not be null`.  (I'm not running in strict mode).

I realise that I could use the keyword DEFAULT in place of some values when preparing the query, but I don't really want to do that.  I would like to be able to write my SQL statements verbatim, rather than put them together with foreach loops, etc.  For example, I would like to use `"INSERT INTO users (user_type, first_name, last_name, password) VALUES (:user_type, :first_name, :last_name, :password)";`

As far as I recollect, this was working fine (i.e. substituting in the correct defaults) until I moved from using ? query markers to named parameters...

Thanks...

Comment: I don't think this can be done this way: a value *is* being sent when bound (because it appears at all!), even if `NULL`. Thus MySQL cannot apply the default value -- because a value *was* specified. There are triggers, but "ick!". One "solution" would be to have a minimal query-generator based off say, a Map. (Still using placeholders, of course.)

Comment: Are you talking about php? Because you mentioned about "Array", probably worth mentioning Array in which language

Comment: (I don't think it *was* working with just using `?` markers with the same insert structure; might want to verify that and, if it does work, see by what magic.)

Comment: @SiGanteng, yes, PHP.  See question title.

Comment: @pst, so would it be more 'normal' for a developer to generate the SQL string by looping through the array?

Comment: @KimPrince I'll tag it as such then

Comment: possible duplicate of [pdo prepared statement insert DEFAULT when the variable in BindParam is null. I tried: IFNULL or COALESCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130583/pdo-prepared-statement-insert-default-when-the-variable-in-bindparam-is-null-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function that accepts the values as parameters. It would have the default values in an associative array. If the value for any of the parameters is null, it would replace it with the default.

eg

```
function setUpQuery($user_type_in, $first_name_in, $last_name_in, $password_in){
       $default_values('user_type' => 'Admin', 'first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Doe', 'password' => 'XXX');
       $user_type = ($user_type_in == NULL)? $default_values['user_type']:$user_type_in;
       .....
      return "INSERT INTO users (user_type, first_name, last_name, password) VALUES ('$user_type', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$password');"
 }
```

Good Point. How about the following:

```
INSERT INTO users(user_type, first_name, last_name,password) values 
(ifnull('$user_type',default(user_type)), ifnull('$first_name', default(first_name)),
 ifnull('$last_name',default(last_name)), ifnull('$password', default(password));
```

Comment: This has the severe disadvantage of not using the DB default values.

Comment: @hgolov, I was hoping to create the SQL statements (and their PDO counterparts) statically and not dynamically because they are static members of a hierarchical mapper class.  I do a check such as "if !isset($this->_PDOInsert) {...}  The default() function approach won't work because the query's parameter types vary with each usage, and are only set once (when the static member is set).

Comment: I see that you marked this as solved. Did it work in your pdo code?